# XSLT - arrays and iterations

Tags: xslt

How can I create an array and iterate through it and get its values?

Example:

```
<xsl:variable name="element">
    <xsl:for-each select="document/items/item">
            <item>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="/@attr">1</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="$element">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Actual Output:

```
<p>0100</p>
```

Should be:

```
<p>0</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>0</p>
<p>0</p>
```

**EDIT: the array should be dynamically generated!**

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I simply will use the version in which this will work :)

Comment: xsl:value-of returns the text value of the current node - an amalgam of the text of the child nodes. Use $element/item or xsl:copy-of or xsl:apply-templates to match the lowest level and generate the p tags.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
<xsl:variable name="element">
    <xsl:for-each select="document/items/item">
            <item>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="/@attr">1</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

and an XSLT 1.0 processor your variable is of type result tree fragment where all you can do is use `<xsl:copy-of select="$element"/>` or `<xsl:value-of select="$element"/>` or where you need to use an extension function like `exsl:node-set` to convert the result tree fragment into a node-set so

```
<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($element)/item">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

should do (with the `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` declared in your stylesheet).

With XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 your variable is a temporary tree with a root node containing some `item` element so there you don't need an extension function but you need to address the `item` elements e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$element/item">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

As an alternative in XSLT 2.0/3.0 you can change the variable declaration to

```
<xsl:variable name="element" as="element(item)*">
    <xsl:for-each select="document/items/item">
            <item>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="/@attr">1</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

to have a variable with a sequence of `item` elements, in that case your

```
<xsl:for-each select="$element">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

would do what you want.

There are no arrays in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

@Pali,

Please share the XML which needs to be transformed .
IT will help .

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="document/items/item">
<item>
<xsl:choose>
 <p>
<xsl:when test="/@attr">1</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
 </p>
 </xsl:choose>
  </item>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```